# Arduino Tiny GPS Library

Tags: c++

[image]

So the problem is TinyGPS++.h keeps saying "no files or Directory". I have added the library manually, did not work. I used Platformio to add the library using there manager, Both of them did not work. TinyGPS.h works but not TinyGPS++ witch is the one I need for my project. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know what fixed it. I came back to the project today and it was not reded out, and the library is magically working. The only thing I did was play video games, and update windows. Eh Go figure. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tutorial [Installing an Arduino Library - learn.sparkfun.com](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-library)

Comment: I have already installed the library that is the problem. After install & rebuilding the index it still says it's not installed.